# fatal python error (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault when using Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, pygame, py2exe

I made small game in `pygame` and `python 2.7` and added submit box with **`Tkinter`**.

It worked fine till I compiled it with `py2exe` / `pygame2exe`.

**Compilation** was error-free.

**But** when i clicked on exe file to launch the application, **compiled-code** threw this error:

```
    fatal python error (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
    This application has terminated in unusal way for more 
    information contact application support team.
```

When I delete Tkinter code and compile it it runs fine.

This is a part of `Tkinter` code:

```
    #i tried importing both with import Tkinter and from Tkinter import*


    if event.key==pygame.K_s:
        subbox=Tkinter.Tk()
        subbox_label=Tkinter.Label(subbox,text="Type your name:")
        subbox_label.pack()
        subbox_entry=Tkinter.Entry(subbox)
        subbox_entry.pack()
        def savescore(a):
            a=str(a)
            print a
            print subbox_entry.get()
            player_name=subbox_entry.get()
            player_score=a
        subbox_button=Tkinter.Button(text="Click",command=lambda:savescore(score))
        subbox_button.pack()
        subbox.mainloop()
```

### UPDATE:

I kicked out Tkinter code line by line and it came up that importing Tkinter causes error!

That means that if I have just:

```
import Tkinter
```

my game won't work!!! **What should I do?**

setup file(pygame2exe but I may accidently delete something inside):

```
try:
    from distutils.core import setup
    import py2exe, pygame
    from modulefinder import Module
    import glob, fnmatch
    import sys, os, shutil
    import operator

except ImportError, message:
    raise SystemExit,  "Unable to load module. %s" % message

#hack which fixes the pygame mixer and pygame font
origIsSystemDLL = py2exe.build_exe.isSystemDLL # save the orginal before we edit it
def isSystemDLL(pathname):
    # checks if the freetype and ogg dll files are being included
    if os.path.basename(pathname).lower() in ("libfreetype-6.dll", "libogg-0.dll","sdl_ttf.dll"): # "sdl_ttf.dll" added by arit.
            return 0
    return origIsSystemDLL(pathname) # return the orginal function
py2exe.build_exe.isSystemDLL = isSystemDLL # override the default function with this one

class pygame2exe(py2exe.build_exe.py2exe): #This hack make sure that pygame default font is copied: no need to modify code for specifying default font
    def copy_extensions(self, extensions):
        #Get pygame default font
        pygamedir = os.path.split(pygame.base.__file__)[0]
        pygame_default_font = os.path.join(pygamedir, pygame.font.get_default_font())

        #Add font to list of extension to be copied
        extensions.append(Module("pygame.font", pygame_default_font))
        py2exe.build_exe.py2exe.copy_extensions(self, extensions)

class BuildExe:
    def __init__(self):
        #Name of starting .py
        self.script = "game_0.3.py"

        #Name of program
        self.project_name = "game"

        #Project url
        self.project_url = "it will be  on sourceforge and indieDB"

        #Version of program
        self.project_version = "0.3"

        #License of the program
        self.license = "gnu gpl 2.0"

        #Auhor of program
        self.author_name = "John Doe "
        self.author_email = "i dont want spam"
        self.copyright = "John Doe 2014"

        #Description
        self.project_description = None

        #Icon file (None will use pygame default icon)
        self.icon_file = "icon.ico"

        #Extra files/dirs copied to game
        self.extra_datas = ["block.png","CHARACTER.png","icon.ico","COPYING.txt","README1.txt","name.txt","score.txt"]

        #Extra/excludes python modules
        self.extra_modules = []
        self.exclude_modules =['AppKit', 'Foundation', 'Numeric', 'OpenGL.GL', '_scproxy', '_sysconfigdata', 'copyreg', 'dummy.Process', 'numpy', 'pkg_resources', 'queue', 'winreg', 'pygame.sdlmain_osx']

        #DLL Excludes
        self.exclude_dll = ['']
        #python scripts (strings) to be included, seperated by a comma
        self.extra_scripts = []

        #Zip file name (None will bundle files in exe instead of zip file)
        self.zipfile_name =None

        #Dist directory
        self.dist_dir ='dist'

    ## Code from DistUtils tutorial at http://wiki.python.org/moin/Distutils/Tutorial
    ## Originally borrowed from wxPython's setup and config files
    def opj(self, *args):
        path = os.path.join(*args)
        return os.path.normpath(path)

    def find_data_files(self, srcdir, *wildcards, **kw):
        # get a list of all files under the srcdir matching wildcards,
        # returned in a format to be used for install_data
        def walk_helper(arg, dirname, files):
            if '.svn' in dirname:
                return
            names = []
            lst, wildcards = arg
            for wc in wildcards:
                wc_name = self.opj(dirname, wc)
                for f in files:
                    filename = self.opj(dirname, f)

                    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, wc_name) and not os.path.isdir(filename):
                        names.append(filename)
            if names:
                lst.append( (dirname, names ) )

        file_list = []
        recursive = kw.get('recursive', True)
        if recursive:
            os.path.walk(srcdir, walk_helper, (file_list, wildcards))
        else:
            walk_helper((file_list, wildcards),
                        srcdir,
                        [os.path.basename(f) for f in glob.glob(self.opj(srcdir, '*'))])
        return file_list

    def run(self):
        if os.path.isdir(self.dist_dir): #Erase previous destination dir
            shutil.rmtree(self.dist_dir)

        #Use the default pygame icon, if none given
        if self.icon_file == None:
            path = os.path.split(pygame.__file__)[0]
            self.icon_file = os.path.join(path, 'pygame.ico')

        #List all data files to add
        extra_datas = []
        for data in self.extra_datas:
            if os.path.isdir(data):
                extra_datas.extend(self.find_data_files(data, '*'))
            else:
                extra_datas.append(('.', [data]))

        setup(
            cmdclass = {'py2exe': pygame2exe},
            version = self.project_version,
            description = self.project_description,
            name = self.project_name,
            url = self.project_url,
            author = self.author_name,
            author_email = self.author_email,
            license = self.license,

            # targets to build
            console = [{
                'script': self.script,
                'icon_resources': [(0, self.icon_file)],
                'copyright': self.copyright
            }],
            options = {'py2exe': {'optimize': 2, 'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True, \
                                  'excludes': self.exclude_modules, 'packages': self.extra_modules, \
                                  'dll_excludes': self.exclude_dll,
                                  'includes': self.extra_scripts} },
            zipfile = self.zipfile_name,
            data_files = extra_datas,
            dist_dir = self.dist_dir
            )

        if os.path.isdir('build'): #Clean up build dir
            shutil.rmtree('build')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if operator.lt(len(sys.argv), 2):
        sys.argv.append('py2exe')
    BuildExe().run() #Run generation
    raw_input("Press any key to continue") #Pause to let user see that things ends
```

**another important thing**:if i import Tkinter before pygame there is no segmentation error but game doesn't run and error window pops out and says this application requested runtime to terminate in unusal way for more information contact app support

Comment: Not sure if it has to do with your issue, but your `command-lambda...` is going to bite you in the future, that's going to call once and only ever once when you assign it, not when its clicked.

Comment: @user2085282 Why? It's creating a lambda function, not calling it.

Comment: @parchment ah, you're correct, i was thinking in terms of no lambda, ignore me.

Comment: Should I try some other module this is really annoying as the submit should not be so important and it takes my time from making other game feautures

Comment: Take a look at this: http://pygame-users.25799.x6.nabble.com/Python-error-pygame-parachute-Segmentation-Fault-td457.html  apparently it's about Pygame loosing focus on Windows.

Comment: Have you performed any fault-isolation efforts to diagnose, on which exact operation the SegFault appears? Pygame's event-loop controls might get in troubles with Tkinter .mainloop(), so be rather specific and post the code, where you have backtracked the SegFault to appear.

Comment: I'll try to remove just parts of Tkinter code thanks

Comment: @user3666197 I did that look at edited question.Help?

Comment: Would you kindly post also your `setup.py` file used for `py2exe` compilation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Did you check py2exe/Bugs?

While it is not exactly the same crash, **the root-cause,** related to Tkinter internal dependence on sub-layer of Tcl & Tk DLL services **seems similar:**

cit.:

"""

Using `Tkinter`, and `bundle_files = 1`, i get an immediate crash.

Here's my setup:

```
    winxp sp2
    py2exe 0.6.8
    python 2.5.1
```

My test file is "`example.py`", as follows:

```
#### start
from Tkinter import *
if __name__ == '__main__':
print "hello"
#### end
my setup.py is as follows:
#### start
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(
options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
zipfile = None,
console=['example.py'])
#### end
```

it compiles just fine, but when running the "`example.exe`" that is produced in the "`dist`" directory, it immediately gets the error message "example.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience".

Using the same `setup.py`, but with `bundle_files = 3` works fine; using bundle_files = 2 causes the same crash.

I hope this is sufficient information to replicate this bug. I will be happy to provide any other info if you need it - just post back here.

"""

### + a there proposed workaround:

cit.:

"""

I "fixed" this by editing `site-packages/py2exe/build_exe.py`,

**adding** "`tcl85.dll`" and"`tk85.dll`" to the "`dlls_in_exedir`" list

-- meaning that **they get put next to the .exe rather than bundled inside it**.

Slightly messy, but much better than bundled=3

"""